# No "Restore Packages" option on right-click package.json on visual studio 2015 update3

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to start with Angular 5 and Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) i need to "restore packages" on right click on 'packages.json'-file, but this option is missing in menu.

Answer (score 0):

Last I used restore packages it was only for nuget. For npm you can simply run:

```
npm install
```

In your command prompt / terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?msclkid=e265dabdd0a311ec9bda6ec23b485e12&view=vs-2022:

npm expects the node_modules folder and package.json in the project root. If your app's folder structure is different, you should modify your folder structure if you want to manage npm packages using Visual Studio.

Looks like the context menu item 'Restore Packages' won't show up unless packages.json is in the project folder. Is yours nested in another folder?